# How do you export react library component with hooks to use in html file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I am getting an error when trying to export a library component to use in a window environment where we will not be using imports, and am getting an error `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`. There is no duplicate version of react as it is being consumed by a simple html file.

[image]

My webpack file looks like

```js
const config = {
    mode: 'development',
    externals: {
      react: 'React',
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname), path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/GlobalNav/index.tsx'),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './global-nav/dist'),
      publicPath: '/',
      library: 'GlobalNav',
      filename: 'globalNav-blog.js',
      libraryTarget: 'window',
    },
  };
```

and exporting a simple component

```
const GlobalNav = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState(33);
  return (
    <div>test</div>
  );
};

export default GlobalNav;
```

and used in a simple html file

```html
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    ></script>

    <!--......-->

    <script src="/globalNav.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function () {
        var root = document.getElementById("root");
        var GlobalNav = window.GlobalNav.default();

        ReactDOM.render(
          GlobalNav,
          root
        );
      })();
    </script>
```

If I remove the use of hooks then it works. How do you export a react component with hooks as a library to be used in an environment without imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the functional component as a function, not as a component.

```
var GlobalNav = window.GlobalNav.default();

ReactDOM.render(
    GlobalNav,
    root
);
```

Try using `React.createElement`.

```
var GlobalNav = window.GlobalNav.default;

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(GlobalNav),
    root
);
```